# need for a valgrind massif stack trace (allocation tree) example

Tags: c++, stack, valgrind, stack-trace

In the [documentation of valgrind massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html), there is a paragraph about the allocation tree.

> However, in rare circumstances stack traces can be malformed, in which case **a stack trace can be a sub-trace of another stack trace**. This means that some entries in the tree may not satisfy the invariant -- the entry's size will be greater than the sum of its children's sizes.

While the documentation hasn't given an example of such case.

An example would be very appreciated to better illustrate the problem even not related to valgrind.